# SDL_DestroyWindow doesn't free memory

Tags: c++, c++11, sdl-2

Basically, in my program I have to create and destroy a window. I always use the same window pointer creating and destroying the contents (texture and render).

I notice a memory leak in this process so I wrote a simple program to verify this, here the code.

The problem has the higher impact on Windows, on Ubuntu at the end of the test the memory is increased only around 3MB (around 236MB on Windows).

```
#include <iostream>
#include "SDL.h"


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

    SDL_Window* mainWindow;
    SDL_Renderer* mainRenderer;
    SDL_Texture* mainTexture;

    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
    {
        mainWindow = SDL_CreateWindow("Memory Leak Test v1.0", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 320, 240, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
        mainRenderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(mainWindow, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
        mainTexture = SDL_CreateTexture(mainRenderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_ABGR8888, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING, 320, 240);

        if (i == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "SDL Memory Leak Tester, please check the amount of memory\noccupied by the process, then press Enter\n";
            getchar();
        }

        SDL_Delay(50);

        if (i == 199)
        {
            std::cout << "SDL Memory Leak Tester, please check the amount of memory\noccupied by the process, then press Enter\n";
            getchar();
        }

        SDL_DestroyTexture(mainTexture);
        SDL_DestroyRenderer(mainRenderer);
        SDL_DestroyWindow(mainWindow);
    }

    std::cout << "Test finished, press Enter to close\n";
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: *"I notice a memory leak"* - how did you notice it? Which allocations are leaking?

Comment: Did you read the code? There are 2 moment when the user can check the occupied memory by the process and the memory increases at each loop

Comment: I just suspect that you are checking for leaks by inspecting process memory consumption in task manager or something similar (which may yield inadequate results) instead of using memory profiler.

Comment: If there's a memory leak, then the amount of memory in use *after the loop* will depend on how many times the loop was executed (try replacing `20` with other values). Does it happen?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat for sure, if I use 40 the amount of occupied memory increases linearly

Comment: A few notes here: The code looks okay and I wouldn't expect it to leak either. Further, I'm with VTT, you're reporting an interpretation ("there is a leak") but without actual observations, which include in particular how you measured and what you measured. Lastly, consider writing a bug ticket, you almost have all required info already. Stack Overflow wouldn't be the place for that though.

Comment: I tried running your code, and it indeed appears to leak. I suggest sending a bug report.

Comment: I don't understand the replies from VTT and Ulrich Eckhardt. Try to run my code, I changed the number of loop to be executed. At the end the process occupied 243.4 MB of RAM, at the beginning 7.3 MB. In which way don't you understand that there is a memory leak?

Comment: Growing process memory counter is not necessary a sign of memory leak. It would also be caused by fragmentation or by use of debug heap. Even if it is a memory leak it would be a good idea to identify its source prior to writing bug reports.

Comment: The problem has the higher impact on Windows, on Ubuntu at the end of the test the memory is increased only around 3MB (around 236MB on Windows)

Comment: "Works fine on my machine". There is no problem in presented code, so please clarify the question - are you looking for workarounds or trying to pinpoint the source of your problem?

Comment: Also, on windows you can use ``dbgapi.h`` and heap check functions to see your leaks and where they come from. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/crt-debug-heap-details?view=vs-2019

Comment: Can't reproduce on windows either. May be related to your SDL version, selected renderer implementation or graphics driver.

Comment: Windows 10 64 bit. Application compiled in 32 or 64 bit mode. SDL 2.0.8

Comment: @Francesco still works as intended even with SDL 2.0.8, although it is quite outdated now. Can you `SDL_RendererInfo info; SDL_GetRendererInfo(mainRenderer, &info);` and print `info.name`? Does it happen if you request software renderer instead? What's your graphics driver?

Comment: Renderer: direct3d. It doesn't happen with SDL_RENDERER_SOFTWARE. Intel UHD Graphics 620